# Flutter - Reusable Widget TextFormField - validation does not work

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I am using a reusable widget and trying to pass a validation before the form is submitted.
But, I am not getting the error message that I should get. I have read the code several times, but do not find where is the problem. If you can have a quick look and tell me what I am missing it would be great.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextFormFieldWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  String hintText;
  TextEditingController controller;
  int maxLength;
  int maxLines;
 // Function onChanged;
  TextInputAction? actionKeyboard;
  String? parametersValidate;
  String? defaultText;
  String? labelText;
  TextInputType? textInputType;
  FocusNode? focusNode;
  bool? obscureText;
  Widget? prefixIcon;
  Function onSubmitField;
  Function? onFieldTap;
  Function? functionValidate;
  String? decoration;
  String? validator;
  //final dynamic Function(String?)? onChanged;


  TextFormFieldWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.hintText,
    required this.controller,
    required this.onSubmitField,
    required this.maxLength,
    required this.maxLines,
  //  required this.onChanged,
    this.labelText,
    this.validator,
    this.parametersValidate,
    this.textInputType,
    this.onFieldTap,
    this.defaultText,
    this.actionKeyboard,
    this.prefixIcon,
    this.focusNode,
    this.obscureText,
    this.functionValidate,
    this.decoration,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TextFormFieldWidgetState createState() => _TextFormFieldWidgetState();
}

class _TextFormFieldWidgetState extends State<TextFormFieldWidget> {
  double bottomPaddingToError = 12;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        primaryColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      child: TextFormField(
        cursorColor: Colors.black,
       // obscureText: widget.obscureText,
        keyboardType: widget.textInputType,
        textInputAction: widget.actionKeyboard,
        focusNode: widget.focusNode,
        maxLength: widget.maxLength,
        maxLines: widget.maxLines,

        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 16.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
          letterSpacing: 1.2,
        ),
        initialValue: widget.defaultText,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: widget.prefixIcon,
          hintText: widget.hintText,
        //  labelText: widget.decoration!,

         // enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
         //   borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
         // ),
        //  focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
        //    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
        //  ),
          hintStyle: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey,
            fontSize: 14.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
            letterSpacing: 1.2,
          ),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 12, bottom: bottomPaddingToError, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
          isDense: true,
          errorStyle: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red,
            fontSize: 12.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
            letterSpacing: 1.2,
          ),
          errorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          focusedErrorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
        controller: widget.controller,
        validator: (value) {
          if (widget.functionValidate != null) {
            String resultValidate =
            widget.functionValidate!(value, widget.parametersValidate);
            if (resultValidate != null) {
              return resultValidate;
            }
          }
          return null;
        },
        onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
          if (widget.onSubmitField != null) widget.onSubmitField();
        },
        onTap: () {
          if (widget.onFieldTap != null) widget.onFieldTap!();
        },


      ),
    );
  }
}

String? commonValidation(String value, String messageError) {
  var required = requiredValidator(value, messageError);
  if (required != null) {
    return required;
  }
  return null;
}

String? requiredValidator(value, messageError) {
  if (value.isEmpty) {
    return messageError;
  }
  return null;
}

void changeFocus(
    BuildContext context, FocusNode currentFocus, FocusNode nextFocus) {
  currentFocus.unfocus();
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nextFocus);
}
```

Widget

```
Widget _buildTextFormField(String myHintText,TextEditingController myController,
      int length,int lines,String myContent) {
    return TextFormFieldWidget(
      hintText: myHintText,
      decoration: 'Test 33',
      controller: myController,
      maxLength: length,
      maxLines: lines,
      onSubmitField: () {},
      validator:checkFieldEmpty( myContent),
    );

String? checkFieldEmpty(String? fieldContent) { //<-- add String? as a return type
    if(fieldContent!.isEmpty) {
      return 'Field empty => Please, change this.';
    }
    return null;
```

View

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: _addFirstTaskFormKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              _buildTextFormField('Task Name',taskNameController,100,3,taskNameController.text),
```

```
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (){

                  if(_addFirstTaskFormKey.currentState!.validate()){
                    print ('validated');
                    //taskItems.taskName = taskNameController.text;
                    //taskItems.notes = notesController.text;
                  }
                }, child: const Text('Press'),
              ),
```

Comment: Are you using form widget on top?

Comment: yes. I will update my code to show it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're relatively new to flutter, don't worry I got you,
FormValidators are used to validate multiple fields declared inside a Form Widget.
Form widget uses a global Form key
declared Like this,

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

and fields
Like this,

```
   child: Form(child:Column(children:[
TextFormField(controller:controller),
TextFormField(controller:controller),
],),),
```

so when you need to validate fields just call,

```
_formKey.validate();
```

in the case above you are making a CustomTextFormField

you don't necessarily need to make it a stateful widget,
use StateLess Widget instead,

```
class CustomTextFormField extends StateLessWidget {
  final TextInputType? keyboardType;
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final FormFieldValidator<String>? validator;
  final ValueChanged<String?>? onSaved;
  final Function(String)? onChanged;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;
  const CustomTextFormField(
  this.keyboardType, 
  this.controller,
  this.validator,
  this.onSaved,
  this.onChanged,
  this.onTap,
  );
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
        keyboardType: keyboardType,
        validator: validator,
        autovalidateMode: autoValidateMode,    
        onSaved: onSaved,
        onChanged: onChanged,
);
}
```

and use it like this

```
    CustomTextFormField(
    validator: (String? val) {
    if(val==null) {
    return "Value cannot be empty";
   }
    return null;
   },
  ),
```

add any other validation that you may want to apply
and on save button call

```
if(_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
  //SaveData
}else {
print("Validation Error")
}
```

Comment: OK, but where in the reusable widget? on the view?

Answer (score 0):

This may be the problem. You're using null values. Flutter has [Sound null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) so this means you can't set variables to null. I'm really curious, does your code even run?

Solution:
Scrap your validator and read through the Flutter Docs. They'll walk you through building a Form with validation [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation)

```
 validator: (value) {
          if (widget.functionValidate != null) {
            String resultValidate =
            widget.functionValidate!(value, widget.parametersValidate);
            if (resultValidate != null) {
              return resultValidate;
            }
          }
          return null;
        },
        onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
          if (widget.onSubmitField != null) widget.onSubmitField();
        },
        onTap: () {
          if (widget.onFieldTap != null) widget.onFieldTap!();
        },


      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: thank you. My code is working, except the validation. I want to validate three TextFormFields before recording the data in FireBase